# 3.3V I2C SDA/SCL but 1.8V VDD?

Tags: i2c, 3.3v

I'm trying to avoid the use of a level shifter in a design, but it would unfortunately require that I communicate at different voltage levels than what I power the device at.

If I communicate with a [sensor](http://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/DS-000176-ICM-20602-v1.0.pdf) from a microcontroller with 3.3V logic level I2C lines, but I power that sensor at 1.8V, am I in for big trouble (permanent damage to the device, inability to communicate)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will almost certainly run into problems. From your datasheet:

[image]

A spec like this most likely indicates the presence of ESD protection diodes on the SCL and SDA lines, connecting them to the power and ground rails.

If you power this with 1.8 V, and connect SCL (for example) through a pull-up resistor to 3.3 V, it will pull the SCL line down to about 2.5 V. This could cause problems with other chip recognizing a high voltage on SCL. The extra current from SCL into the VDDIO supply could cause other unexpected (and unpredictable) behavior.

It may be possible to operate your sensor with VDDIO at 3.3 V while the main VDD is at 1.8 V. I don't see anything to prevent it listed in the characteristics tables, but I didn't read the complete datasheet to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Your concern of operating an MCU at 3.3V and a sensor at 1.8V is a valid one. But it is not a reason to avoid using a level shifter.

A suitable level shifter takes just two additional SMT resistors and two N-Channel MOSFETs. Both FETs can be deployed in a very small SOT-363 or similar 6-pin SMT package. Cost is really really small.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2CBi-directionalLevelShifter)*</sup>

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/ds30203-79162.pdf)*</sup>